# Rolling 12 Month Salesforce in MicroStrategy

Tags: sql, oracle, salesforce, microstrategy

I made cube in MSTR WEB connecting to my SalesForce database, I have a date field in the form "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format, how do I keep it as a rolling 12 month? 
I tried the add_month(current_date, -12) that didnt work.

```
SELECT
  P.ID PROBLEM_ID,
  CAST(P.BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C AS DATE) OPENED_DATE, 
  parent_account__C

FROM BMCSERVICEDESK__PROBLEM__C P 

WHERE P.COUNTRY__C  != ''  
AND BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C >= add_months(current_date, -12)
```

Error:

> Error in accessing information from the external data source (Database
>   Instance: (DataImport)[0], Error: Execute Query failed. Error type:
>   Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLExecDirect. [42000:-11: on
>   SQLHANDLE] [MicroStrategy][ODBC Salesforce
>   driver][Salesforce]Unexpected token: ADD_MONTHS in statement [select 
>   P.ID PROBLEM_ID,  CAST(P.BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C AS DATE)
>   OPENED_DATE,   parent_account__CFROM BMCSERVICEDESK__PROBLEM__C P
>   WHERE P.COUNTRY__C  != ''  AND BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C >=
>   add_months(current_date, -12)])

Thanks!

Comment: what data type is `BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C` ? It seems you are trying to compare from the first day of the last twelfth month, is it what you want?

Comment: Not sure bout the data time, but when I run the whole table it sin date/time format. I'm not looking at the first day, the current  day - 12 months

Answer (score 0):

What was your problem/error ? What is the type of P.BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C ?

**EDIT:**

Use this first:

> SELECT  data_type, data_length FROM all_tab_columns where table_name =
>   'YOUR_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN'

```
SELECT 
P.ID PROBLEM_ID, CAST(P.BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C AS DATE) OPENED_DATE, parent_account__C

FROM BMCSERVICEDESK__PROBLEM__C P 

WHERE P.COUNTRY__C  is not null
AND trunc(BMCSERVICEDESK__OPEN_DATE_TIME__C) >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

You can trunc `sysdate` also...

Comment: With add_months I get "Unexpected token: ADD_MONTHS in statement" error. Type is date/time based on what I can see when I run the whole table

Comment: @darkpunk use the query to get the data_type (under EDIT).

Comment: Sadly the that query doesn't work. I don't think that MSTR web queries work like the regular SQL query when connected to salesforce. Anyways I appreciate the help with this. Your query should work but I guess its the system error not the query error.

Answer (score 0):

The base question would seem to be when do want to start the clock for your running 12 months. Using what you do now where "date_column >= '2019-04-01 00:00:00'" then updating monthly(?) it seems you the 12 months FROM THE 1st of the month. So try

```
date_column >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'month'), -12)
```

You indicated you get an error using add_months. This implies a syntax in your statement, but you did post it so we cannot see wait it might be.  
BTW Oracle does not separate data and time data types. All date types contain both both date and time components.

Comment: Tried this still get the "Unexpected token: ADD_MONTHS in statement " error :/

Comment: Post the exact SQL statement you ran, and the exact complete error message. If what you ran is part of a larger code block post it.  The error indicates you have a syntax problem. Nobody can help you with it without being able see it. Just saying what error, even what the error is,  alone is completely useless. Also, please update the question don not post your code as a comment. Perhaps you should review [ask].

Comment: I have edited the post to show what I tried and the error message I receive.